# I am unable to boot into ubuntu something weird than purple screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.04, bootloader, nomodeset

I don't understand this and when i boot into grub menu and edit quiet splash to nomodeset something like I/O error sda flags ....etc  appears and doesn't boot. When I normally boot in without any change , it shows up and automatically shutdowns without booting in.

Comment: Your question is attracting "close as unclear" votes. I suggest you reword it to state explicitly what you are seeing in each of the two cases. For example, I have no idea what "it" refers to in your last sentence.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad hard disk. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` application, select the proper disk, and then the SMART Data. Take a screenshot and edit it into your question for me to see. Depending on if the Data windows scrolls more data, you may have to take 2 screenshots to capture it all. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.